# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 115

Tags: php

when trying to run a php script I get the error 'Unexpected T_IF'
Yes, it is a botnet script, however I am just researching about networking, I have no intentions to use it.
And yes, I did try putting a semi colon, no luck.
Full script: https://github.com/Visgean/Zeus/blob/translation/source/server%5Bphp%5D/install/index.php

```
"`r_reports_db`          bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_reports_db_edit`     bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_reports_files`       bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_reports_files_edit`  bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
/*EVAL_BEGIN*/if (configBool('jabber_notifier'))return    /*THIS IS ERROR*/
"\"`r_reports_jn`          bool NOT NULL default '1', \".";
/*EVAL_END*/

"`r_system_info`         bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_system_options`      bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_system_user`         bool NOT NULL default '1', ".
"`r_system_users`        bool NOT NULL default '1'";

//RЎRєSЂReRїS, C <P ± RѕS, P ° Rј.
$_TABLES['botnet_scripts'] =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatening a string which you suddenly interrupt with an `if` statement. That is an obvious syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at php. So would moving it out of the r reports section fix the issue?

Comment: If you remove the line with the `if` and fix the next line, e.g.  
`"r_reports_jn          bool NOT NULL default '1', ".`
it should work